# Creating tags for a specific language feature

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

In the past couple of days someone has started adding a new tag [guard-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guard-statement) on a bunch of questions (yesterday there were 4, now they are 17).

`Guard` is a feature of Swift so it's not something that you would use on its own. Since you would always need to add the `swift` tag to provide enough context, is the `guard-statement` tag really needed?

As I was reviewing edits to questions, I always rejected this change and noticed that other reviewers shared my opinion. However like I said before the number of questions tagged with the tag has increased in the past 24 hours.

I wanted to check you guys and see what's the position on creating tags for language specific features 
I wanted to send a message to the user creating the tags but wanted to check with you guys before.

**Should we be creating / maintaining tags for language specific features?**

Comment: Well, that tag is exactly as useful as the tag [tag:if-statement], the differences between them are trivial at most.

Comment: I thought about that. but `if` is something you find in any language while `guard` is (for now) swift specific.

Comment: There are a lot of tags specific for language feature. In AngularJS, you have a tag for `ng-repeat`, `ng-show`, ... :)

Comment: @Mistalis yes, but should we? It seems unlikely that there are people out there who can answer questions on one but not the other!

Comment: In my opinion, it can bring precision to the question and can help to quickly identify the problem. A real problem could be that these tags get too specific, and can not be understood anymore. But I think we are not there yet...

Comment: @Mistalis those tgas are supposed to be in burnination process for quite some times. Unlike ng-repeat and so on, guard can be seen as a concept, like a lambda, which might get supported on more languages. So this tag as definitively more value than angularJS's one. I can't say if it has enough value to have his own tag though guess it's to the community and experienced users.

Comment: @Walfrat Why should `unless` / `guard else` / `if not` or however you want to name it get more ubiquitous? It doesn't seem to be any better than `if` and a negation...

Comment: IMO this tag is useless, but it's just IMO. On the other hand, I'm 100% positive that going on an edit spree like OP is doing is frowned upon. There's even faulty edits among the just useless ones (I had to do some rollbacks). This behavior should not be encouraged.

Comment: @Eric, just to make sure I understand. which part is frowned upon? adding the tag or rejecting those edits? What's the best way to communicate this to the user that is actually making those edits? how do we efficiently stop the further use of this tag while it still has a small number of Questions associated to ti ?

Comment: @AlexDrenea `which part is frowned upon?` Editing many, many posts in a row just to add a useless tag (and without improving anything else). `What's the best way to communicate this to the user` No idea. I tried a simple sentence with a smiley but OP wasn't really receptive, so I stopped there (except for [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907546/using-guard-in-swift-struct-does-not-initialize-all-properties#comment63185507_33907546), no smiley here).

Comment: Haskell has [`guard`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard) too, even though it's different. [`unless`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:unless) seems pretty much the same thing with a different name.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes but i just totally don't know if some features like this can have a legit tags here of if others tags like this are just created by users again and again and then stay there even when we don't want too. To me it's just like the implementation of a prerequisite.

Comment: Your title is very general, but your question body and answers are specific to the Swift guard statement. [Here's another example where point 7) mentions the JS tag `intersection-observer`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381107/202229). Please either edit it into your question, and/or vote/answer on that Meta question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this tag should exist.

Tags should only be created if questions can be asked with that single tag only <sub>(looking for meta source for this now)</sub>.  Because this construct is specific to Swift, questions can not (or rarely) be asked about the construct outside of Swift.

Answer (score -4):

In a general part, I think that a concept/features available may have a tag. If the feature is really relevant.

The fact that a feature may be available for only one language is irrelevant, things goes so fast, if the feature is popular and relevant it will get quickly on some others. As an example you can take lambda expression which has been adopted in many language that didn't supported it natively. It has like 10 tags around it, some may not have value, the tag  `lambda` has now 12k Questions.

In your case, if I follow what was said in comments and in my opinion. A tag like this has no value. However you can be sure people will use it.

I checked for `conditional` tag. There is quite a lot tags around it. `conditional-statement` seems fair enough to cover this or even `if-statement`.

But since swift called it something else, people will use that name.