# R language-specific tags: r-timedate, r-factor, r-model-formula etc.?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation, terminology

Correct me if my understanding is wrong, but I thought in general we're not supposed to incorporate the language name into tag names, except in cases where disambiguation is needed. And even then, if something is a common construct to statistical languages, we shouldn't call the tag "r-...". Here are some R-language-specific tags, some need attention:

- **[r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor)** wiki says *"The factor is a data type in the R language, used to encode categorical or enumerated data."* Really, all statistical languages have this, Python pandas does too. But *"categorical-factor"* may be unwieldy. If we call this factor, we have to call it [r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor) to disambiguate from integer factorization. Suggest: keep; unless consensus is to rename to *"categorical-factor"*. Update: there is also a [categorical-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/categorical-data), which is mostly pandas, some R. Are these mergeable?
- **[r-model-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-model-formula)** 5 questions; needs tag wiki. Model-formula is common to statistical languages like R, STATA, MatLab and Python [patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package. **Strongly suggest rename this `model-formula`?**
- **[r-timedate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-timedate)** Time & date transformations are always somewhat different in each language, but I don't see that R needs one in particular. We already have generic tags [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime), [datetime-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime-format), [date-arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-arithmetic). **Suggest: Delete**. Update: it got deleted in 2016/7.

(While I'm at it, we used to have a separate [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame) as the right tag for the R data-frame, not [dataframes], as per this obsolete meta post: [Warn [r] users from adding [dataframes] tag instead of [data.frame] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318933/warn-r-users-from-adding-dataframes-tag-instead-of-data-frame-tag) . But now they've been merged.)

Reference: [Creating tags for a specific language feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326285/creating-tags-for-a-specific-language-feature)

Comment: @Contango I think you were the first to use [tag:r-timedate]?

Comment: I prefer the opposite: remove the generics one.

Comment: @Braiam: there are 100+ languages on SO. Many questions are indeed generic, or at least generic to a family of languages. Removing generic tags is not feasible, nor desirable. The last thing we want to do is create the Cartesian product of all possible [language-concept] combinations.

Comment: I chaged [tag:r-datetime] to [tag:datetime]. And [tag:r-model-formula] had 5 posts, 3 of those had already lm or regression tags, so I removed it, now only 2 left. I would remove them too, but for now left it for others to decide. And last tag [tag:r-factor] has ~300 posts, anyone for a manual clean-up?

Comment: [tag:r-factor] should be re-named to [tag:factor] or maybe even better merge with [tag:categorical-data].

Comment: @zx8754: please slow down and let's figure it out. Stop doing things hastily without getting consensus. Please reinstate with the name [tag:model-formula]. I didn't say the fact that [tag:r-model-formula] was currently only used 5 times was evidence it wasn't needed - it actually is needed. R, STATA, MatLab and Python patsy all use model-formulas, so it is not an R-specific thing.

Comment: As to [tag:factor] being distinct from [tag:categorical-data], that's an old chestnut with the R community. 'categorical data' is a concept; 'factor' is a specific R-language implementation, with specific quirks. Although there is overlap, they get used somewhat differently. So stop and wait for the R community to comment.

Comment: I meant 'categorical data' is a concept,and common to most statistical languages; 'factor' is a specific R-language implementation

Comment: Sorry, if it seemed hasty. I think [tag:r-timedate] is agreed and gone. [tag:r-factor], see my comment above. [tag:r-model-formula], I think popularity says a lot here, regression/model/formula is probably a lot older than SO. If up until now it wasn't used/needed, then it shouldn't exist.